# Add custom fields to the Stripe checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I have integrated my website with [Stripe checkout](https://checkout.stripe.dev/configure)  but I need to capture some additional data while the customer is checking out. However, I can't really find out how to add custom fields to the checkout page. Some say I need to use `stripe.js`, but I still can't really find how I can integrate `Stripe.js` with the checkout page. All I want is adding some custom fields to the checkout page such as contact number. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have very limited control over the Checkout page since it's a redirect. For more control you would need to integrate on your own site with [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?ui=elements).

Comment: The v3 stripe checkout is absolute garbage. Use the v2 version. It's visually nicer and has more options.